# Проблема с аргументом один работает другой нет

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

Всех приветствую решил, у меня такая проблема один аргумент работает а другой не хочет в чем проблема понять не могу, при работе с аргументом `hex` все работает но при аргументе `path` программа выбрасывает ошибку, заранее благодарю  за помощь

```
import argparse

args = argparse.ArgumentParser()
args.add_argument('hex',help='ip target',metavar='')
args.add_argument('-p','--path', help='path',metavar='')

args = args.parse_args()

hexInput = args.hex

hexcode = ''.join(reversed([r'\x' + hexInput[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(hexInput), 2)]));print("\x0a"+hexcode)

rev = path[::-1]
print(rev.encode('hex'))
```

*hexmirror.py -p /bin/sh*

выкидывает ошибку:

> Error: the foolowing arguments are required

Comment: Ошибку надо бы копировать, а не перепечатывать. Причем копировать целиком, а не половину. Пока что понятно только, что не хватает каких-то аргументов.

Comment: `hexmirror.py -p /bin/sh` - ну так у вас `hex` - обязательный аргумент, а вы его не передаете

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел ответ мне надо было просто добавить группы (Извините если не правильно написал, я не знаю как правильно )

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import argparse

args = argparse.ArgumentParser()
args.add_argument('hex',help='hex or path',metavar='')


group = args.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-b','--byte',help='Byte ;)',action="store_true")
group.add_argument('-P','--Path',help='Path ;)',action="store_true")



args = args.parse_args()



def HexMirror(hex_code):
    a = hex_code
    hexcode = ''.join(reversed([r'\x' + a[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(a), 2)]));print(hexcode)

def HexPath(path):
    rev = path[::-1]
    return rev.encode('hex')


def main():
    if args.byte:
        HexMirror(args.hex)
    if args.Path:
        print "0x" + HexPath(args.hex)  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```